# WP User Query fails when searching meta queries and search columns

Tags: users, meta-query, user-meta, wp-user-query

I'm building an advanced User search using WP_User_Query but experiencing some unusual behaviour. I'm trying to search with a term that I know exists in the user_nicename and user_email fields but fails to return when I include meta_query in the $args.

Using the simple query below, when searching the users table data, WordPress returns everything as expected because the term exists in the user_nicename and user_email.

```
$args = array (
    'fields' => ['ID'],
    'count_total' => true,
    'order' => 'ASC',   
    'orderby' => 'display_name',
    'search' => '*'.esc_attr( $search_term ).'*',
);
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
```

Then however, when I introduce a meta_query into the search to check against the user meta, the query fails to return any results at all - even though it's matching data previously using the simple statement. The meta_query makes the $args look like so:

```
$args = array (
    'fields' => ['ID'],
    'count_total' => true,
    'order' => 'ASC',   
    'orderby' => 'display_name',
    'search' => '*'.esc_attr( $search_term ).'*',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'first_name',
            'value'   => $search_term,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'last_name',
            'value'   => $search_term,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'description',
            'value' => $search_term ,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
```

I'm determining which columns to search from the users table by implementing the following filter:

```
function inc_columns( $search_columns, $search, $this ) {
    $search_columns[] = 'user_email';
    $search_columns[] = 'user_nicename';
    $search_columns[] = 'display_name';

    return $search_columns;
}
add_filter('user_search_columns', 'inc_columns', 10, 3);
```

Any light that can be shed on why this is would be great.

Comment: I should've mentioned - the search term I know doesn't appear in any of the fields referenced in the meta_query, however, I'd still expect the user to be returned because of it matching other criteria

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combining a meta query with a search for a keyword will return posts which match both the search query and the result of the meta query (even if you're using `relation => OR` in the meta query).

[This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/208939/80532) covers a way to achieve your expected outcome for posts, which – you need to modify the query before it fetches the result. That will need to be modified to be used with a WP User Query however. I've made an attempt at a solution that searches for the search term in the `user_nicename`, `user_email` and your meta fields - untested, so might need tweaking.

```
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'user_meta_OR_search');
function user_meta_OR_search($q){
    if ($search = $q->get('_meta_or_search')){
        add_filter( 'get_meta_sql', function( $sql ) use ( $search ){
            global $wpdb;

            // Only run once:
            static $nr = 0; 
            if( 0 != $nr++ ) return $sql;

            // Modify WHERE part:
            $where = sprintf(
                " AND ( %s OR %s OR %s ) ",
                $wpdb->prepare( "{$wpdb->users}.user_nicename like '%%%s%%'", $search),
                $wpdb->prepare( "{$wpdb->users}.user_email like '%%%s%%'", $search),
                mb_substr( $sql['where'], 5, mb_strlen( $sql['where'] ) )
            );

            $sql['where'] = $where;

            return $sql;
        });
    }
}

// Then, where you do the searching:
$search_term = "test";

$args = array(
    'fields' => ['ID'],
    'count_total' => true,
    'order' => 'ASC',   
    'orderby' => 'display_name',
    '_meta_or_search' => '*'.esc_attr( $search_term ).'*',
    "meta_query" => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'first_name',
            'value'   => $search_term,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'last_name',
            'value'   => $search_term,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
              ),
        array(
            'key' => 'description',
            'value' => $search_term ,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);

$the_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
```

Another solution is to use two queries – one which does a general search using `s` and one searching using `meta_query`:

```
$args1 = array (
    'fields' => ['ID'],
    'count_total' => true,
    'order' => 'ASC',   
    'orderby' => 'display_name',
    'search' => '*'.esc_attr( $search_term ).'*'
);

$wp_user_query1 = new WP_User_Query($args1);
$args2 = array (
    'fields' => ['ID'],
    'count_total' => true,
    'order' => 'ASC',   
    'orderby' => 'display_name',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'first_name',
            'value'   => $search_term,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'last_name',
            'value'   => $search_term,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'description',
            'value' => $search_term ,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
$wp_user_query2 = new WP_User_Query($args2);

$result = new WP_User_Query();
$result->results = array_unique( array_merge( $wp_user_query1->results, $wp_user_query2->results ), SORT_REGULAR );
$result->post_count = count( $result->results );
```

This will merge the results of the two queries into a third query containing the final search results. I haven't tested this, so it might need some tweaking!

Comment: Thanks, @Emil. Was hoping to avoid running two separate queries and combining the results because of the volume of users on the website and the impact that may/will have on performance. Will try to find a way of achieving the outcome using the link you provided! Cheers :)

Comment: Yeah, that could be a problem. The link I provided replaces the `s` variable and instead searches directly in the post title, so if you know what fields you want to search in, it shouldn't be too hard to modify the code. I'll give it a go for you as well and edit my answer!

Comment: The updated answer might be helpful!

Comment: Thanks, @Emil. Looks perfect and all makes sense! I'll have a play around with it and let you know what happens. Thanks for your help, appreciate it!

Comment: No problem! If it turns out to have helped you a lot, feel free to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark ✔ next to it. :)

Comment: Unfortunately doesnt work anymore because they made `$results` private and `pre_user_query` is executed after `get_meta_sql`

Answer (score 0):

Because [Emil's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/248674/174130) answer is deprecated by now here is my update solution which uses `pre_get_users` filter instead of `pre_users_query` to attach the correct filter and also remove it again afterwards so it only runs once for this query:

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_users', 'user_meta_OR_search');
function user_meta_OR_search($q){
    $search = $q->get("_meta_or_search");

    if (empty($search)) return $q;

    $fn = null;
    $fn = function ($sql) use ($search, &$fn) {
        global $wpdb;

        // Only run once:
        static $nr = 0;
        if( 0 != $nr++ ) return $sql;

        // Modify WHERE part:
        $where = sprintf(
            " AND ( %s OR %s OR %s ) ",
            $wpdb->prepare( "{$wpdb->users}.user_nicename like '%%%s%%'", $search),
            $wpdb->prepare( "{$wpdb->users}.user_email like '%%%s%%'", $search),
            mb_substr( $sql['where'], 5, mb_strlen( $sql['where'] ) )
        );

        $sql['where'] = $where;

        remove_filter("get_meta_sql", $fn);

        return $sql;
    };

    add_filter("get_meta_sql", $fn);
}
```