# How to make a search query if not found in post table then search in postmeta table?

Tags: wp-query, query

can any one tell me that how can i make a query which search in two table. if not found in post table , search in postmeta table.

Comment: $where .= ' AND ((' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE '.$search_term.') OR ('. $wpdb->postmeta. '.meta_value LIKE '.$search_term.'))';

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using meta query ('meta\_query') with a search query ('s')](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78649/using-meta-query-meta-query-with-a-search-query-s)