# get_meta_sql hook is not firing

Tags: wp-query, hooks, meta-query

`WP_Query` uses `WP_Meta_Query`.  I thought this calls the `WP_Meta_Query::get_sql()` to define the meta query SQL which is where the `get_meta_sql` filter is applied.

I can't get the `get_meta_sql` filter to fire.  I thought it would fire with `$var = new WP_Query($args);` but it isn't.

I need to alter the sql before it is run.  A lot of sources specify this hook.  I can't get it to work.  **Alternatively** - any suggestions on how to alter the WP_Query sql before it's run is appreciated.

I'm referencing:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_meta_sql/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/
- https://weplugins.com/wordpress/how-to-use-get_meta_sql-filter-in-wordpress/
- [Query to get result by Title or Meta along with tax_query parameter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/403040/query-to-get-result-by-title-or-meta-along-with-tax-query-parameter)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43734845/how-to-give-or-relation-in-tax-query-and-meta-query-wordpress

The actual code is long/complicated, I can't even get it to fire with dummy code in a blank plugin.  Just trying to figure out why this hook won't fire where I'm expecting it to.

Comment: There's also the [`post_clauses` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_clauses/) for SQL modifications.