# How do I improve this admin query snippet to avoid generating duplicate results on non-meta searches?

Tags: plugin-development, custom-field, wp-admin, search

I've been playing around with code snippets which add meta data to admin searches.

The best snippet I've found was written by [Stefano on this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11758/extending-the-search-context-in-the-admin-list-post-screen).

However, it appears to have 1, annoying bug when searching non-meta terms.

Here are some grabs from my local dev install. I've printed the 2 MySQL queries onto the screen.

#### View of the single CPT post I'm using to test

[image: View of the single CPT post I'm using to test]

#### This is the code working as expected and allowing me to search meta data from admin

[image: This is the code working as expected and allowing me to search meta data from admin]

#### Unfortunately the code creates duplicates on non-meta matches, in this case on post title

[image: Unfortunately the code creates duplicates on non-meta matches, in this case on post title]

#### A grab showing the post status, post type and post ancestors of dupes

![A grab showing the post status, post type and post ancestors of dupes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0p3O.png)

Here is the code I'm running, it's basically the same as Stefano's, but with my crude attempts to make the query work.

```
/*
 * Search custom fields from admin keyword searches
 */

function rel_search_join( $join ) {
    global $pagenow, $wpdb;
    if ( is_admin() && $pagenow == 'edit.php' && $_GET['post_type'] == 'listings' && $_GET['s'] != '') {    
        $join .= 'LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->postmeta . ' ON '. $wpdb->posts . '.ID = ' . $wpdb->postmeta . '.post_id ';
    }
    echo '<br><strong>JOIN</strong>: ';
    print_r ( $join );
    echo '<br>';
    return $join;
}
add_filter('posts_join', 'rel_search_join' );

function rel_search_where( $where ) {
    global $pagenow, $wpdb;
    if ( is_admin() && $pagenow == 'edit.php' && $_GET['post_type']=='listings' && $_GET['s'] != '' ) {
        $where = preg_replace( "/\(\s*".$wpdb->posts.".post_title\s+LIKE\s*(\'[^\']+\')\s*\)/", "(".$wpdb->posts.".post_title LIKE $1) OR (".$wpdb->postmeta.".meta_value LIKE $1)", $where );
        $where = str_replace( "OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending'", "", $where );
        $where = str_replace( "OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private'", "", $where );
        $where = str_replace( "OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft'", "", $where );
        $where = str_replace( "OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future'", "", $where );
    }
    echo '<br><strong>WHERE</strong>: ';
    print_r ( $where );
    echo '<br>';
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'rel_search_where' );
```

Comment: Maybe it lists the revisions too?

Comment: I thought I was only looking at published, because I removed pending, private, draft & future. Didn't notice a revision type.

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't appear to be a "revisions" status: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status

Comment: try to print_r the post type or the post id in one of the columns, i think revisions are post types, so if you can see revisions, you have that also in the results. But i can also see that you only display results from the listings post type, so i think i'm wrong. But its worth a try:)

Comment: Added a new grab with post statuses, post types and post ancestors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A `GROUP BY` statement can group your posts after the `JOIN`. For Wordpress you can use the [`posts_groupby`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_groupby) filter.

```
add_filter( 'posts_groupby', 'my_post_limits' );
function my_post_limits($groupby) {
    global $pagenow, $wpdb;
    if ( is_admin() && $pagenow == 'edit.php' && $_GET['post_type']=='listings' && $_GET['s'] != '' ) {
        $groupby = "$wpdb->posts.ID";
    }
    return $groupby;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for your work on this, folks. This code got me most of the way there, but using WP 3.8 I was getting a SQL non-unique table/alias error, so I made some changes. For it to work on my setup I had to set a $wpdb->postmeta alias that was used in the JOIN statement. I also check only check once to see if the hooks should be used so they don't fire every time. Hope this helps someone!

```
global $postmeta_alias, $is_specials_search;
$cpt_name = 'special';
$postmeta_alias = 'pdpm'; // Change this to whatever your custom post type is
$is_specials_search = is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) && $_GET['post_type']==$cpt_name && isset( $_GET['s'] );

// Extend search to include 'description' field
if ( $is_specials_search ) {
  add_filter( 'posts_join',      'pd_description_search_join' );
  add_filter( 'posts_where',     'pd_description_search_where' );
  add_filter( 'posts_groupby',   'pd_search_dupe_fix' );
}

function pd_description_search_join ($join){
  global $pagenow, $wpdb, $postmeta_alias, $is_specials_search;

  if ( $is_specials_search )  
    $join .='LEFT JOIN '.$wpdb->postmeta. ' as ' . $postmeta_alias . ' ON '. $wpdb->posts . '.ID = ' . $postmeta_alias . '.post_id ';

  return $join;
} // END search_join

function pd_description_search_where( $where ){
  global $pagenow, $wpdb, $postmeta_alias, $is_specials_search;

  if ( $is_specials_search )
    $where = preg_replace(
     "/\(\s*".$wpdb->posts.".post_title\s+LIKE\s*(\'[^\']+\')\s*\)/",
     "(".$wpdb->posts.".post_title LIKE $1) OR (".$postmeta_alias.".meta_value LIKE $1)", $where );

  return $where;
} // END search_where

function pd_search_dupe_fix($groupby) {
    global $pagenow, $wpdb, $is_specials_search;

    if ( $is_specials_search )
      $groupby = "$wpdb->posts.ID";

    return $groupby;
} // END pd_search_dupe_fix
```