# How to reset HTML filter input fields on CPT list page?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

On the `edit.php?post_type=my_cpt` page I have dropdowns for filtering the list. There is a Filter button by default, but there is no Clear or Reset button. I can't seem to find help on how to create this button because 'filter' pulls up a lot of unrelated information on the search engines.

I understand this can be done in jQuery - create a click event for a button that redirects to the CPT list page, and there is an HTML button to reset the form, but I also need the results to be refreshed and this form is not currently setup for Ajax - so the page needs to reload with all input fields set to their defaults.

What is the best approach to handle this?

**EDIT**

An image of default filters can be viewed on [this page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11758/extending-the-search-context-in-the-admin-list-post-screen). Note the 'Filtra' button. I need to place a 'Clear/Reset' button right after the Filter button that will clear the form and resubmit it so that the displayed results will reflect default filter settings.

Comment: Can you provide an image?

Comment: I made an edit and included a link to a page here on SE. It shows the Filter button in a different language, but the UI is similar. I do have some dropdowns for custom filtering and sorting, but I don't think any of my custom filters/columns change this question or influence a potential answer.